# How can I tell if the drop-down list of a `ComboBox` is open?

Tags: python, user-interface, combobox, wxpython

In wxPython, how can I tell what is the state of the drop-down list of a `ComboBox`, that is, is it open or closed?

I'm trying to implement a `ComboBox` that allows the user to delete a value from the list by opening the drop-down list, selecting an item, and pressing delete (*Edit:* when I say selecting here I mean just highlighting an item, without clicking it yet, so the drop-down list remains open).
I can bind the delete key, and I know how to delete an item, the only problem is the delete key has a different function if the drop-down list is closed (its usual function in the text field), which I want to preserve.

Answer (score 2):

Use EVT_COMBOBOX. That fires when the user selects something from the list. I would store the selection in an instance variable (like self.currentSelection). You may want to store the previous selection too. Then when the user presses "delete" you can delete the new selection or show a prompt asking them if they really want to delete that item.

UPDATE: As mentioned in the comments, I think ComboCtrl is a good alternative. You can find examples of its usage at the following:

- The wxPython demo package
- http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/combo/wx.combo.ComboCtrl.html
- http://robsworldoftech.blogspot.com/2010/02/wxpython-example-for-wxcomboctrl-with.html

Comment: `EVT_COMBOBOX` only fires while the drop-down list is closed, or right after it is closed, and this means the user could not use the delete key in the usual editing of the text field. I want to be able to choose an item while the drop-down list is open, and press delete while it is highlighted but not yet finally selected.

Comment: You can't select something in a combobox and press delete while the combobx is open. Maybe you should use a ListBox or try the ComboCtrl instead.

Comment: I don't want to use a `ListBox` because I don't want the whole list to be shown to the user unless he chooses to see it. `ComboCtrl` seems interesting because it has the method `IsPopupShown` which looks like its exactly what I need. However, it's complicated to use `ComboCtrl` - how would you create the most simple combo box with it?